# How to start App Expose without using Force Touch or the keyboard?

Tags: mouse, trackpad, expose

I know there was a way to trigger App Expose, by pointing the mouse cursor over an dock icon, and scrolling the mouse wheel.

As far as I remember, it was something I had to enable with the "defaults" command in Terminal.

Unfortunately I don't remember how to enable this feature, and I can't find it on google nor on AskDifferent. Could somebody point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following command will enable mouse scroll to open App Expose

```
defaults write com.apple.dock scroll-to-open -bool TRUE; killall Dock
```

To disable the gesture, use

```
defaults write com.apple.dock scroll-to-open -bool FALSE; killall Dock
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to trigger this as a Hot Corner or with a mouse click in High Sierra (available from the Mission Control area of System Preferences), though these only work for the active application. I assume you're asking about the click-and-hold behavior that [was available](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission_Control_(macOS)#Usage) in Snow Leopard.

The closest I can see now is to right-click on an application in the Dock and select "Show All Windows". While it takes two clicks, it does serve to pull up the App Exposé interface for the desired application.

[image: App Exposé via Dock menu]